# Return row count between 2 dates always returns 0

Tags: mysql, sql

wonder if any aficionados can help me. I am trying to get the number of records between two dates, I made this query really simple using some posts i found on here, it always returns 0.

**date_added is a timestamp**

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM item 
WHERE date_added >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND date_added <= NOW()
```

I also tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM item 
WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `CURDATE()` for the beginning date and `NOW()` for the ending? Also, what data type is your `date_added` column?

Comment: @KenWhite I think I was just trying different functions when I found it wouldn't work as expected. Doesn't work either way.

Comment: @KenWhite Ahh, timestamp(), I feel this may be a problem.

Comment: The first query works for me.  Did you answer what data type 'date_added' is?

Comment: @DougKnudsen ^ Just above, it is timestamp()

Comment: Are the `id` values by any chance null? `COUNT` won't count null values.

Comment: id is just a column of auto_increments, so all integers. If i removed the date clause, so just count the ids I get 21 which is what I expected

Comment: Do you need to do something like DATE(date_added) to get the data types in sync?

Comment: @DougKnudsen Just tried it when I realised their types didn't match :S

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the `timestamp` info, and also add a tag for the specific database you're using (SQL Server, MySQL, or whatever else), as there are differences between them. What gets displayed when you `SELECT TOP 1 date_added FROM item`?

Comment: Just selecting the date_added column as in, no changing from timestamp() returns the date in this format: `2013-04-12 16:55:11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re ran this query this morning and it worked just fine, so I'm not sure what went wrong last night other than the hour. Thanks to everyone's input.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM item 
WHERE date_added BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

worked fine as did

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM item 
WHERE DATE(date_added) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Hope that may be of use to someone.

Answer (score 2):

Use DATE(NOW()) and DATE(date_added) for comparison of dates in mysql. It will give you date part of the timestamp.

For Example 
CURDATE() is 2008-11-11 and 
NOW() is 2008-11-11 12:45:34

One is date, other is timestamp. You should take either both dates or both timestamp. One solution I've told above.